# How to protect your vm - honeypot from being used in a DoS attack in GCP?

Tags: user-interface, google-cloud-platform, firewall, ddos, honeypot

I deployed my vm-honeypot in GCP, but it was used by adversaries to DoS attack. Google shut down my vms with honeypot. I want to limit the DoS attack output bandwidth for the future. I would be grateful for any ideas on how to do this.

I haven't worked with GCP before, I set everything up from the GUI.

The project was started on new $300 - free tier account for educational purposes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Google has mechanisms in place to protect its cloud infrastructure and its production services. These mechanisms are designed to ensure that no single service can overwhelm the shared infrastructure and to provide isolation among customers using the shared infrastructure. Details of these mechanisms are out of scope for this
[document](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf).

If you wish to have an additional layer of security against DDOS attacks, we would recommend [Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/cloud-armor-overview).